# Can the actual scope of "lattice theory" be summarized as "algebraic order theory"?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Lattice and order theory are often mentioned together. So I wonder how lattice theory is "intended" to differ from order theory.

- Lattice theory became important in the context of universal algebra. The characterization via algebraic operations instead of the order relation might hence be the important point.
- The generalization of intersection and union in set theory, of "and" and "or" in logic (and maybe of the analogous operations for "quotient structures") might also be the motivation for investigating lattices. But even so these are contexts where the non-trivial results of lattice theory matter, I don't have the impression that introductions to lattice theory care much about these "applications".

The difference between these two possibilities can be seen by looking at more concrete question regarding the scope of lattice theory: Is semi-lattice theory part of lattice theory? Is the "logic of partitions" part of lattice theory? Is formal concept analysis part of lattice theory?

Both semi-lattice theory and formal concept analysis are definitively within the scope of "algebraic order theory", but the logic of partitions is not. If on the other hand the generalization of logical operations were the central theme of lattice theory, then the logic of partitions would be part of it, but semi-lattice theory would not, and formal concept analysis would be a border case.

(I hope it became clear enough in which sense I'm "confused" about the scope of lattice theory.)

Comment: I think that order theory is more set theoretical in some way, while lattice theory is more algebraic (because of the Stone duality and related stuff). Maybe I´m wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "scope", and what is your motivation? Semilattice theory is connected to lattice theory insofar as a semilattice is a reduct of a lattice.  One could argue that the "scope" of lattice theory extends beyond "pure" lattice theory, since lattices show up so often when studying other mathematical structures (e.g., lattices of: subalgebras, congruence realtions, ideals, normal subgroups, partitions, etc).  However, "pure" lattice theory might be confined to the abstract theory of lattices. I think scope is hard to define, and I'm not sure why you would want to define it.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo I mean by "scope" how I would tag an article, whether I would present it on a lattice theory conference, publish it in a lattice theory journal, or search in lattice theory publications for related information. My concrete concern is [single sorted formal concept analysis](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156016/has-the-single-sorted-case-of-formal-concept-analysis-been-investigated), motivated by the answer to a [question about the concept lattice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630678/relation-between-concept-lattice-and-dedekindmacneille-completion).

Comment: I see.  That makes sense.  Thanks for elaborating on the motivation.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I happened upon it.  One thing about lattice theory that I find most fun is the interplay between the algebraic and order-theoretic point of view.  For example, I've had a lot of fun in recent years thinking about how to understand algebraic notions such as congruences and quotients order-theoretically.  And believe it or not, this "fun" is also very useful for studying some lattices that arise in algebraic combinatorics.